# how to get separate numbers by minute in php

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5

how do I get only the first 2 numbers separated by a sign -
for example 1928-25-23-54
I will only take 192825 from numbers 1928-25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```php
$a = '1928-25-23-54';
preg_match('/^\d+-\d+/', $a, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

Comment: There're no needs to escaped the hyphen, and capture group is useless and slow down the process.

Comment: Well done, you got my vote.